# Angular: Call a function after an array is populated in another function

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the code sample I am working with. a public variable is declared and that is populated in the function loadData(). I would like to call the function processItemList only after the itemList is populated in the loadData() function. The code below is the way the itemlist is populated and and is already in place. How do I do this without changing the loadData() function much. At this time, the processItemList function is fired but it finds the itemList empty.

```
public itemList: ItemClass[];
 processItemList() {
    do somethign here...
 }
 
 
 loadData(<parameter>:any){
     this.APIservice.GetAllData(<parameter>).pipe(mergeMap(res => {
      ..
      ..
      ..
      ..
      ..
      ..
      
    })).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp.length > 0) {

        this.itemList = resp.map(x => new ItemClass(x));
    }};
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call processItemList inside the subscribe method right after the itemList gets populated:

```js
public itemList: ItemClass[];
 processItemList() {
    do somethign here...
 }
 
 
 loadData(<parameter>:any){
     this.APIservice.GetAllData(<parameter>).pipe(mergeMap(res => {
      ..
      ..
      ..
      ..
      ..
      ..
      
    })).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp.length > 0) {
        this.itemList = resp.map(x => new ItemClass(x));
        // Put here the function call:
        this.processItemList();
    }};
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. that helped.

Answer (score -2):

You can transform `itemList` to setter function if there is no way to modify code in `loadData` like:

```
set itemList(value: ItemClass[]) {
   this._ itemList = value;
   this.processItemList();
}
get itemList(value: ItemClass[]) {
   return this._ itemList;
}
```

But I believe it is better to update `loadData` function

Comment: this is not the correct answer - somehow I lost a point for downvoting your incorrect answer.  this person is invoking a cloud function - they should be using .then to get the result and filter it BEFORE returning it to the client.

Comment: @chrisburd what do you mean under "cloud function"? Which .then do you suggest to use if in question no promises but observables? What do you mean under "client"? If client/server interaction - the question is about angular so my answer is dedicated to client-side solution

Comment: you should be using promises with any http outside invocation that uses a git - this gives you state and await without having to program it.  .subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp.length > 0) {

        this.itemList = resp.map(x => new ItemClass(x));
    }};  should be

.then(resp => {
      if (resp.length > 0) {

        this.itemList = resp.map(x => new ItemClass(x))
    }}).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)). 

I write. a lot of functions for a lot of clients I thought you were using a cloud function for a particular vendor.

Comment: Please, use google to read about Observables and how they differ from Promises

Comment: this is Twilio but its the same thing https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-javascript-using-promises-rest-apis-nodejs. its good for you to be able to read up on it here.

Comment: where is your observable - I see no such declarations.  you should use a behavior subject with rxjs and use promise chaining which is the correct way to program your get function.  please don't insult other people because you think you are clever - I clearly said I THOUGHT you were using a cloud function.  it still doesn't change the fact that this should be a promise chain - the proper way to write functions in 2021.  